# SponsorLink-error when upgrading to SDK-styled project

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I recently upgraded my project from .Net 4.5.1 to .Net 6 using the upgrade assistant from Microsoft. After doing that, I get the following compiler error:

> SponsorLink analyzer did not receive the required
> MSBuildProjectFullPath compiler-visible property. This is typically a
> package authoring error which can be fixed by installing the
> Devlooped.SponsorLink package or adding the following MSBuild item to
> the project: `<CompilerVisibleProperty Include="MSBuildProjectFullPath" />`.

I have only a reference to `log4net v2.0.15` and `ICsharpCode.SharpZipLib 0.85.4.369` as package-references within my project-file. However, as those didn't change while upgrading I doubt the error comes from there. I have no idea which projects want sponsorship here, as I didn't change any references.

I added the `CompilerVisibleProperty` into my project as suggested within the error (I'd needed to add `DesignTimeBuild` as well for whatever reason). However, I have no idea what the error is actually about and how adding those attributes is related to it.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <CompilerVisibleProperty Include="MSBuildProjectFullPath" />
  <CompilerVisibleProperty Include="DesignTimeBuild" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue. my **temporary fix** was to use a lower version of the nuget package that was causing the issue.

I easily found which package I had to downgrade by reading the project the "Sponsorlink Analyzer" issue was happening, and tested by changing the nuget version.

This is not the best solution and there is definitely a better way, but this could help you going further.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to specify which version of the NuGet package addressed the issue for you?

Comment: I faced this issue whilst using **Moq (version 4.20)**

By the way, an issue about sponsorlink on Moq on the github repository has been created recently, it seems to be causing some privacy issues...
https://github.com/moq/moq/issues/1372?s=09